# How to filter out elements across a particular dimension

Tags: numpy, torch

Let's say tensor `a` has shape `(128, 20, 10)`. I'd like to filter this tensor into tensor b of shape `(128,19,10)` based on a condition: In each `(20, 10)` matrix there's one row I'd like to remove where the sum of columns are zero. How do I do this via slicing?

I should be able to do something along the line of:

```
mask = a.abs().sum(dim=2) != 0
a = a[mask]
```

But this gives me the wrong shape.

Comment: Is all I need a post reshape? `a = a[mask].view(128,19,10)` ?

Comment: The shape is 1d, but are the values correct?